# SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict is empty in ie 10

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, people-picker

I created a Search display Template for booking events. 
In this exists a Peoplepicker usercontrol, that preloads the current user.

This works very well on all browsers... except IE...specially IE with Useragent String with IE 10.

When I set this useragent string (with the developer console) the variable SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict ist empty, bit in the frontend the Peoplepicker will be shown.

[image]

What can cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying with the same username in all browsers! If you are, then check if there is any JS library that is being blocked or not loaded. 
Also, can you try in IE 11 (maybe install in a VM and try to see if you experience the same behavior?)